# React - Accessing refs DOM node "checked", how to get each checkboxes value then set a value on each of refs node "checked" inside sub component

Tags: reactjs

How to get refs DOM node "checked"? This is for check multiple checkboxes if i get access to refs node checked is true or false then i can trigger check all checkboxes in one stroke. Another problem is i can't figure out on how to get each checkboxes value via loop then set a value on each of refs Dom node "checked" inside child component i have a finish project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qimm2x but the problem is its declarative i mean straightforward but what about if the logic is inside a child component like the code below.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import  { render } from 'react-dom';

class Items extends Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props);

        this.state = {

            categories: [
                {
                    id: 0,
                    name: "category 0",
                    items: [
                        { name: "select all", id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999) }
                    ]

                },
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: "category 1",
                    items: [
                        { name: "item 1", id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999) },
                        { name: "item 2", id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999) }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: "category 2",
                    items: [
                        { name: "item 3", id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999) },
                        { name: "item 4", id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999) }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    name: "category 3",
                    items: [
                        { name: "item 5", id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999) }
                    ]
                }
            ],
        };
    }

    render() {
        const { categories } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                {categories.map(cat => {
                    return (
                        <ItemCategory
                            {...cat}
                            key={cat.id}
                            categories={categories}
                        />
                    );
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class ItemCategory extends Component {

    constructor(props){
    super(props);
       this.ItemChecked = this.ItemChecked.bind(this);
    }  

    ItemChecked(e){
        let tValue = e.target.value;

        if(tValue === 'select all'){
            for (const cat of this.props.categories) {
                for (const item of cat.items) {
                    console.log(item.name)
                }
            }
        }   
    }

    render() {
        const { items, name } = this.props;

        const getItems = items.map(item => {
            return item;
        });

        return (
            <div>
                <div>-{name}</div>
                <ul>
                    {getItems.map(item => {
                        return (
                            <li key={item.id}>
                              <label>
                                <input
                                    type="checkbox"
                                    value={item.name}
                                    ref={item.name}
                                    onClick={this.ItemChecked}
                                />
                                {item.name}
                              </label>
                            </li>
                        );
                    })}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function App() {
    return <Items />;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a fat arrow function on onClick.

```
onClick = {e => this.ItemChecked(e)}
```

Comment: Here's a Medium post that explains it in [detail](https://medium.com/@machnicki/handle-events-in-react-with-arrow-functions-ede88184bbb)

Answer (score 0):

```
const ItemChecked = (e) => {
    const tValue = e.target.value;

    if(tValue === 'select all'){
        for (const cat of this.props.categories) {
            for (const item of cat.items) {
                console.log(item.name)
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Just declare `ItemChecked` as an arrow function and remove the binding on the constructor, also there is no need to use let when defining `tValue`.